# EF Core throws an Exception when performing an order by on a field from a select when using an includes

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to page some data in my sqlite database using EF Core. As part of the paging I need to sort the data before I get a page. This query performs an includes to fetch some child data and I am using select to put the data into a new type so I can sort on the values in the select.

The code to reproduce is as follows.

```
var query = Table
            .Include(x => x.Furniture)
            .Select(x => new SelectedFurniture
            {
                House = x,
                IsSelected = true
            });

var t = await query
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.House.Code)
            .Skip(skip).Take(take)
            .ToListAsync();

var o = await query
            .Skip(skip).Take(take)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.IsSelected)
            .ToListAsync();
```

When the query outputs to 't' it works fine. When the query outputs to 'o' it throws a NullReferenceException. The actual query in my code is more complex, this is just a simplified example to demonstrate the problem.

I have learned the following by experimenting

- If I remove the include both queries will work fine.
- The includes and select work fine if I don't do an order by.

What I am trying to do is build a query that will let me page data out of the database into a new type however there are over 100k records so I need to order that data before reading it out. The actual order by requires fields that are created during the select. I do not have the option of loading all the data into memory and ordering it then paging it.

Does anyone know if the code I am writing is invalid or beyond what EF Core is capable of? Does anyone know what alterations I might need to my query to perform this operation?

Here is the class SelectedFurniture in case it is relevant.

```
public class SelectedFurniture
    {
        public DummyEntity DummyEntity { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: you have to post SelectedFurniture too.

Comment: I have added the class

Comment: Thanks but why I can't  see House property?

Comment: Tbh I have trimmed down real classes to show the bare minimum to demonstrate the bug. The problem does not appear to be related to the actual classes. They all work fine when I use any two of the include/select/order by. It is this combination that causes the bug and only when using a property in the select that did not exist in the db entity.

Comment: It appears that others have had the same issue when I read this github issue page https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/11900

Answer (score 0):

Problem here that `x.Code` has no projection in source query. EF Core cannot predict which field is needed.

Correct source query and everything should work

```cs
var query = Table
            .Select(x => new SelectedFurniture
            {
                House = x,
                IsSelected = true,
                Code = x.Code
            });
```

Note that, if you are doing custom projection `Include` is completely ignored. So just don't waste your time writing includes in such case.

Comment: Please explain the errors since  OrderByDescending, skip or take don't use include

Comment: @Serge, you still use includes with custom projections and you want explanation why it is ignored for yourself?

Comment: I mean with include or without include it will be the same errors. PO doesn'  try to  use x.Furniture for select in  t or o, since there is no any select

Comment: I have answered why he has error. Why it works without include - miracle and probably EF Core bug.

Comment: Why do I need to do this? As shown above, the query result into 't' works just fine without projecting Code into the new type. In fact the the code in SelectedFurniture is not the one being used in the first query. The 'code' being ordered is the one from the db entity class.

I am able to use both includes and Select as long as I don't use order by on any of the new types properties. 

EG I can order on the dummyEntity and its properties. But I cannot order on any other property in SelectedFurniture

Comment: Simple answer:  if you have projected property in first query - you can use it later in subsequent queries, if not, you have problems. If you want I can explain In more details, but not today.  But everything here is from commons sense. EF trying to understand from where property value is taken (Table, column) and cannot trace it.

Comment: @JosephDevlin  Pls , just remove include and tell us if you still have the same errors.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv IMHO we are just waisting our time. If PO included furniture then he is using it and  he posted no the real code since I can't see how furniture is used.   I offer to close the question since we need the real code to make the answer.

Comment: @Serge, I'm not. I can read Linq queries from parsing perspective (I've spend a lot of time doing that) and I see problems from the first sight.

Comment: @Serge if I remove the includes it works fine. If I remove just the order by it works fine. If I use them both, it throws an exception